default way to create a polars series from a dictionary?
In pandas I have the habit to create small series from dictionary. This is practical, notably for plotting.
typically:
import pandas as pd

data = {1:2, 2:6 ,4:5}

pd.Series(data).plot();

However, polars Series doesn't seem to accept dictionary. Is there a pythonic way to do this ?

For pandas 1, 2, 4 end up as the Series index - does that actually affect the resulting plot? Would you need to use a 2-column DataFrame in Polars to get a similar result?

I don't think there is a shorthand equivalent for Polars.
In Polars s.plot() ends up calling s.to_frame().with_row_index().plot
s = pl.Series(data.values())

s.to_frame().with_row_index()
# shape: (3, 2)
# ┌───────┬─────┐
# │ index ┆     │
# │ ---   ┆ --- │
# │ u32   ┆ i64 │
# ╞═══════╪═════╡
# │ 0     ┆ 2   │
# │ 1     ┆ 6   │
# │ 2     ┆ 5   │
# └───────┴─────┘

But as Polars 
does not have an "index" - you would need to create a 2-column DataFrame directly.
pl.from_pandas(pd.Series(data).to_frame().reset_index())
# shape: (3, 2)
# ┌───────┬─────┐
# │ index ┆ 0   │
# │ ---   ┆ --- │
# │ i64   ┆ i64 │
# ╞═══════╪═════╡
# │ 1     ┆ 2   │
# │ 2     ┆ 6   │
# │ 4     ┆ 5   │
# └───────┴─────┘

e.g.
data = {1:2, 2:6, 4:5}

(pl.DataFrame({"index": data.keys(), "values": data.values()})
   .plot.line(x="index", y="values")
)


